# PHP Generating .zpl files

Tags: php, pdf, zpl

I wrote web service which will generate label from certain parameters and will return it as PDF. Now I must improve it by returning generated label as PDF or ZPL format.

Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge on working with ZPL. What is ZPL? Is it some kind of file format? What is used for? How its generated? Any open-source PHP libraries for it?

It would be nice if someone would provide some whitepapers or some kind of reference about ZPL.

Web service is written in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(programming_language)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what i was looking for! Cheers